# I'm getting a "No resource found" error for a button's id. How can I solve it?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-button, android-resources

I'm starting on basic Android development. I'm trying to implement a simple app where in clicking a button will cause a toast message to pop up. But while coding for responding to the click of the button, I'm getting this error:
"No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/button1')."

I tried renaming the button using Properties & XML file, as a hard-coded string, but to no avail. I viewed some questions here too, but there were minor errors such as "@id+" instead of "@+id" in them. There are no such errors in my code. Others suggested importing the R file as "import com.example.R;", but I'm using only this application, and nothing from outside that would need importing. Still, I added that import statement, just for the sake of it. It did not help either. So I'm finally posting this question.

I'm labeling the statements that Eclipse red-lines as errors as "<-- ERROR (num)" for reference.

Here's the part of button's Java code:

```
final Button btn_Toast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); <-- ERROR (1)
            btn_Toast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Here's your toast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

And here's the XML for the the screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/button1" <-- ERROR (2)
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="View In Toast" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are the LogCat errors. When I opened LogCat, there were a lot of them, and didn't know which ones to paste here. So I kept in mind the last time stamp, and run the app again, which generated new error entries with newer time stamps. The new errors are the ones I'm posting here.

```
07-06 07:33:39.947: E/memtrack(1877): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-06 07:33:39.947: E/android.os.Debug(1877): failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-06 07:33:42.447: E/memtrack(1888): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-06 07:33:42.447: E/android.os.Debug(1888): failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-06 07:33:43.007: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-06 07:33:43.007: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-06 07:33:43.007: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-06 07:33:43.007: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-06 07:33:43.017: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1437272830
07-06 07:33:43.017: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
07-06 07:33:43.017: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-06 07:33:43.017: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): Process: com.example.helloworld, PID: 1899
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-06 07:33:44.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     ... 11 more
07-06 07:33:45.527: E/StrictMode(710): class com.android.launcher2.Launcher; instances=2; limit=1
07-06 07:33:45.527: E/StrictMode(710): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.android.launcher2.Launcher; instances=2; limit=1
07-06 07:33:45.527: E/StrictMode(710):  at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
07-06 07:33:53.297: E/WindowManager(383): Starting window AppWindowToken{b33d6950 token=Token{b36f6438 ActivityRecord{b2fc6570 u0 com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity t18}}} timed out
```

Comment: A mistake in the question, its "com.example.helloworld.R" in the part about the import statement.

Comment: I removed the `android:id="@id/button1` line from the GUI xml file. The error went away, but when I run in an AVD, it gives me "Unfortunately, Hello World has stopped working" error!!  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your RelativeLayout does not need the button1 identifier, as the line is stating that you want to make the identifier for that layout the same as the button identifier (which you don't).

In a more general sense, errors related to R.id.* values usually occur because the field is not in your R.java file. This file is automatically generated from the resource data in your application.

For example, if you create a new string element in your strings.xml file in the values directory

```
<string name="app_name">Application</string>
```

an entry will be created in the R.java file to match that:

```
public static final int app_name=....
```

The same thing will happen when you add a new button (or other control) to your layout.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

The value of the android:id field will get a static reference value generated for it in your R.java file because you are indicating a declaration of the field by prefacing it with the (+) sign. You can then use in the findViewById methods to search for it or elsewhere in your XML as a reference.

---

The second issue you're having is most likely due to the location you're trying to put the button listener code. If you have a MainActivity.java class with a static Fragment declared within it, you need to make sure your button listener is created inside the fragment class, if your button XML is inside a fragment XML.

When you create a new project, you will usually have the follow hierarchy:

```
src/main/java/com.package/MainActivity.java
src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml
                   /fragment_main.xml
```

Your MainActivity.java file will declare a MainActivity class and a static Fragment class (PlaceholderFragment in the default, I think).

So if you put your button XML inside fragment_main.xml, your button listener needs to go after the view inflater inside the onCreateView method and be modified slightly to the below:

```
final Button btn_Toast = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn_Toast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Here's your toast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

You would search for the element within the rootView and you would use the current view context in the toast creation.

The PlaceholderFragment class will end up looking like this:

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        final Button btn_Toast = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn_Toast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Here's your toast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated above, its compiles properly, but then I get "Unfortunately....stopped working." when I launch it in the AVD.

Comment: You're running into a NullPointerException by attempting to use a view (the button) before it is created. Make sure that you're creating the listener in the fragment that the button XML is in. I've edited my answer to provide additional information.

Comment: I've added the LogCat error entries, if you want to refer to them. And I do not understand what you mean to say by "Make sure you're... XML is in".

Comment: With the code you provided to create your button listener, you are searching within the main activity for the button with that ID. If the button XML that you provided is not within the activity_main.xml and is instead inside a fragment_main.xml, you need to put your button listener code inside the onCreateView method within the fragment class instead of the onCreate method in the activity class.

Comment: My button is in fragment_main.xml. The code:
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  final Button btn_Toast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

  btn_Toast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Here's your toast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
  }
 }`

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem. Take a look at my above edits (below the linebreak). The onCreate method is looking within the activity_main layout, which doesn't contain the button. You'll want to put the code inside the onCreateView method of the fragment.

Comment: So I move the code from "btn_Toast(setOnClickListener......);" inside the OnCreateView method?

Comment: Basically. You'll need to modify it slightly as I mention in the answer above. Prefacing findViewById with rootView will search within the view that was just inflated.

Comment: Done!! Thanks buddy!! Phew!! Thank you again!! It worked!! It worked!! Your efforts appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from the RelativeLayout element :

```
android:id="@id/button1"
```

It causes an error because there is no existing id "button1".

You need to use `@+id/button1` to create a new id, which is exactly what you have done in the button element.

Comment: I tried it, the error goes away and it compiles. But then in the AVD when the app launches, it says "Unfortunately, Hello World has stopped working".

Comment: You will need to share the logcat here for us to have any clue of what the error is.

Comment: What do you want from LogCat? Everything? or Just errors?

Comment: Just the errors. You can edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: There you go. I've posted the log.

Comment: The logcat says there is no activity named "com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.MainActivity". Recheck if that's really the name. I suspect that in your manifest you have used "com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity" for the `android:name` attribute. You should use ".MainActivity" . The first "." is shorthand for your application package, which is "com.example.helloworld".

Comment: it is ".MainActivity", instead of "/.MainActivity". Take a look:
` <activity
            android:name="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: ok it looks good. If the button code is in a fragment, make sure it is in `onActivityCreated()`, not `onCreate()`. Referring to layout resources in `onCreate()` will cause NPE because it is too early in the fragment lifecycle. You can be sure that the layout is inflated only in `onActivityCreated()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line :

```
android:id="@id/button1"
```

from the RelativeLayout, use it only at the button - Go to Eclipse --> Project --> Clean , and then try to run the app..

EDIT:

IF it's not working , try to change the line:

```
android:id="@id/button1"
```

at the RelativeLayout to:

```
android:id="@id/RelativeLayout1"
```

And then again - Go to Eclipse --> Project --> Clean , and then try to run the app..

Comment: Not trying to be smart-a** or over-smart, but I had renamed the id of the RelativeLayout to "layout1" from the previous "button1".
Anyways, I tried your latest suggestion. I cleaned the project, but the error still remains.